# Dativ und Akkusativ mit "dankbar"

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality

Ist folgender Satz grammatikalisch korrekt?

> Peter, dem den Einkauf zu tragen ich dankbar war, lachte auf.

Und ist tatsächlich zu verstehen, dass ich Peter (für) das Tragen dankbar bin?

Comment: Der Satz ist grammatisch korrekt, allerdings sehr gestelzt. Außerdem sollte es besser *tragen zu dürfen* statt *zu tragen* heißen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grammatisch ist der Satz

> Peter, dem den Einkauf zu tragen ich dankbar war, lachte auf.

korrekt.

Allerdings sagt der Satz aus, dass du Peter den Einkauf trägst und dafür dankbar bist.

> Peter, dem den Einkauf tragen zu dürfen ich dankbar war, lachte auf.

Gemeint ist aber offenbar, dass Peter den Einkauf trägt und du ihm dafür dankbar bist. Der Satz sollte also besser lauten:

> Peter, dem ich für das Tragen des Einkaufs dankbar war, lachte auf.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach geht weder aus dem ersten noch aus dem letzten Satz eindeutig hervor, wer den Einkauf trägt.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Das tut es sehr wohl, was man durch Umstellen des Einschubs leicht sieht: **Ich** war dankbar, den Einkauf zu tragen.